SOQL help with ProcessInstance related objects
I'm trying to do a soql query to get me the processInstance record and the related ProcessInstanceNode, and steps. Currently i can get 2 out of the 3 connected, but i can't figure out why i cant get all 3. Any help is appreciated
Query that works:
SELECT ProcessInstanceId, ProcessNodeId, ProcessNodeName

FROM ProcessInstanceNode

WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN

(

SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId = 'abc1112222'

)

Now when i try to add the steps in I am unable to get the correct nesting.
SELECT ProcessInstanceId, ProcessNodeId, ProcessNodeName

FROM ProcessInstanceNode

WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN

(

SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM StepsAndWorkitems) FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId = 'abc1112222'

)


Your child select in semi-join does nothing. If you want to query 2 child objects you just do SOQL on the parent and put sub-queries into SELECT
I think what you are looking for it is
SELECT Id, 
    (
        SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments 
        FROM StepsAndWorkitems
    ),
    (
        SELECT ProcessInstanceId, ProcessNodeId, ProcessNodeName
        FROM Nodes
    )
FROM ProcessInstance 
WHERE TargetObjectId = 'abc1112222'

I used Salesforce Inspector to figure out the Relationship name for ProcessInstanceNode
